# Logging component using log4j in java/java EE application

Tags: log4j

I'm trying to build a component for application level (java/java ee) logging using log4j.where i can create the jar of the component and put it in class path of any application  and use it. Below approach i have followed

1. I override log method like debug , trace, info etc.
2. single and multiple argument substutution e.g. `MessageFormatter.format("Hi {}. My name is {}.", "Alice", "Bob");` will return the string *"Hi Alice. My name is Bob."*.
3. say for example for trace message

   ```
   public boolean isTraceEnabled() {  return logger.isTraceEnabled();}

   public void trace(String msg, Throwable throwable, Object... args) {
       log(isTraceEnabled(),throwable,msg,args);//
   }

   private void log(boolean isEnabled, Throwable throwable, String msg,Object... args)
   {

       if(throwable!=null){
           String message=MessageFormatter.getFormattedMessage(throwable);//Formated the exception message 
           msg=msg+message;
           throwable=null;
       }

         if (args == null || args.length == 0) {
               logger.log(FQCN,LEVELmsg, throwable);
           } else {
               if (isEnabled) {
                   String formattedMsg = MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(msg, args);//single and multiple argument substutution 
                   logger.log(FQCN, UtilConstant. Level.TRACEformattedMsg, throwable);
               }
           }
   }
   ```

My aim is to build the component which can cater all the Java EE applications. Is that two approach sufficient or I need to do more on that. Please help.

Comment: What does this do that log4j (or slf4j or others) do not already do?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me you're reinventing the wheel. Check out the [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/), it can do the things that you're aiming to implement, and it shields you from underlying messaging system, which you can change at any time (it works with log4j out of the box, too).